# Access file being written

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

We are planing to migrate a portal from one platform(A) to another(B) and for this, a utility is provided by the vendor to generate XML for A which will be used by us to migrate to B.

Now this utility has a bug that after generating the relevant XML, it doesn't terminate, rather it keeps on appending static junk nodes to it.

For this purpose, I am writing a C# utility to terminate the application when the XML starts getting junk nodes.

Can I access the file which is already being written as below and be assured that it won't error out

```
var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Also, just to confirm, when a file is being written, the new content is appended to already existing file and it does not first flushes out everything and then write the updated content.(I'm almost sure that I am right on this).

Comment: Looks nothing bad, but why cant you just try ant see whats happens?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the utility keeps the file open in write mode the whole time. It may process the data in-memory in chunks and then write to the file in chunks, but more likely it will just keep the file open for writing, keeping it locked. In that case, you cannot read from it until the utility releases the lock.

Comment: any workaround? as I cannot modify the utility as it is provided by the vendor

Comment: What about User Mode File system? For example [this one supports .NET](http://dokan-dev.net/en/about/). The idea is to make a proxy for the file system driver that will intercept all write/flush operations from the app.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be easy... If there is some way you could detect that the real conversion was finished, you could kill the utility and post-process the XML.

Comment: @neleus: Dokan is not a file system, it is a library for creating file systems... I'm not aware of any functioning user-mode file system on Windows but it would certainly be an interesting route.

Comment: I could detect the end of conversion only by reading the file. I suppose there is no other way @RoyDictus

Comment: I've moved my comment to answer, so you may accept it.

Answer (score -1):

What about User Mode File system? For example [this driver supports .NET extensions](http://dokan-dev.net/en/about/). The idea is to make a proxy for the file system driver that will intercept all write/flush operations from the app.

Comment: I would like to know the reason of the downvote. What is wrong with my answer?